# How multipurpose themes like Betheme include all child themes inside the same Domain name without using sub-domain?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

Does anyone know how the themes like [Betheme](http://themes.muffingroup.com/be/splash/) include all demos (child themes) inside the same root? By using just single sub-domain for all 200+ demos (childes)

Answer (score 0):

They use many WordPress installations in subdirectories: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Each subdirectory has full WordPress core, BeTheme theme, specific options and content in database. They do not create sites using child themes. On all sites BeTheme is used.

You can check it, for example, here: http://themes.muffingroup.com/be/personaltrainer/. Press Ctrl+U on this site, then Ctrl+F, enter `/wp-content/themes` and you will see that active theme is `betheme`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Is there more detailed guide or tutorial which will cover it?

Comment: I gave a link to Codex when installation of WordPress in subdirectory is discussed. It contains sufficient info.